# How do I add 2 unsigned 1 byte numbers in Intel assembly?

Tags: assembly

I'm just starting to learn writing assembly autodidactically.

How Can I add two 1 byte integers using linux on x86_64.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)?

Comment: There are two primary approaches - 1) convert them both to 16-bits (or larger), and then add them, or b) just add them, but keep in mind that the carry flag will hold the possible 9th bit of the sum...

Comment: doesn't `add al, bl` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to learn asembly is to write what you want the processor to do in a higher language, such as C, and then see what the compiler generates.

```
unsigned char addition (unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
{
  return a+b;
}
```

Sometimes this leads to some bizarre, but valid, assembler constructions:

```
movzbl  -4(%rbp), %edx   ;a
movzbl  -8(%rbp), %eax   ;b
leal    (%rdx,%rax), %eax  ;return a+b
```

This time, the `LEA` instruction is used to add two 8 bit numbers stored in 64 bit registers, instead of the expected `ADD` instruction. The key is that these registers have been initialized using the `MOVZX` instruction, which fills all unused bits (up to bit 31) to 0. The same example, written using Intel syntax, goes as this:

```
movzx eax,[rbp-8]  ; A -> eax
movzx edx,[rbp-4]  ; B -> edx
lea eax,[rax+rdx]  ; A+B -> eax
```

One can think that it's odd to add 64 bit registers when only 32 bits of them have been initialized. Taking into account that bits 8 to 31 have been initialized to 0 using the `MOVZX` instruction, whatever happens to the upper half of `RAX` is not important. The lower 8 bits of RAX will contain the 8 bit result of our addition (which may, or not, overflow)

Visual Studio, when no optimizations are enabled, generate a more "predecible" version the assembler version of this function, which you can study, along with its original C code:

NOTE: this has been compiled using 32 bit code generation.

```
unsigned char addition (unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
{
00EA10A0  push        ebp  
00EA10A1  mov         ebp,esp  
    return a+b;
00EA10A3  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp+8]  
00EA10A7  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
00EA10AB  add         eax,ecx  
}
00EA10AD  pop         ebp  
00EA10AE  ret
```

Both compilers try to use its full size registers even if only a little part of them is really needed and this causes both end up using the MOVZX instruction to load an 8 bit value into a much larger register. Use signed chars and you will see what happens.